# Does <authentication mode="Forms"> in web.config always generate automcomplete="off" in ASP.NET?

Tags: autocomplete, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I have a website with  in ASP.NET working fine. However, it becomes really annoy after a while that username/password needs to be re-entered every time even in our dev environment. The thing I noticed about our site is that FF/IE would not even prompt us to remember the username/password after login.

In the code, there is no autocomplete="off" setting anywhere, so I'm just wondering if this is the default behaviour of ASP.NET's form authentication to always generate input box/form with autocomplete="off" attribute; and if there's any way to remove the tag.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250393%28VS.85%29.aspx) but it should also be possible to specify this in the forms properties:

```
<asp:textbox id="UserName" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="None" />
```